# What major monetary policy actions were taken during the Great Recession (2007-2009)?

Tags: macroeconomics, monetary-policy, federal-reserve

What major monetary policy actions were taken during the Great Recession (2007-2009)?

Quantitative easing and unconventional policy actions such as asset purchases and "forward guidance". I think I'm missing some things.

Comment: Is this for homework?

Comment: Ya kind of, I'm trying to gather some different viewpoints on the topic, in addition to my own. This is only part of the question. I broke it up because someone complained that it was too vague and large of a question. Whole question is What major fiscal and monetary policy actions were taken during the Great Recession (2007-2009)? What impact did they have on U.S. economic performance?

Comment: I think this is a good question. I don't know what actions were taken. It'd be nice to have a list of the major points.

Comment: @Amy, unfortunately it doesn't look like your question is going to be answered? Did you work out the answer by yourself? If so, I think it would be appreciated if you put it here because it's a good question.

Answer (score 3):

First, the interest on reserves and the fed funds rate changes:

[image: Interest on Excess Reserves and Effective Fed Funds Rate Log Scale]
Source: [FRED](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/graph/?g=k4S2#0)

Second, we can roughly see the pattern of the QE actions by looking at the balance sheet of the Fed.

[image: All Federal Reserve Banks: Total Assets]
Source: [FRED](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/WALCL#0)

For details on the timing of quantitative easing actions, see Figure 2 from Fawley and Neely (2013):

[image]
[image]
Source: [Four Stories of Quantitative Easing](https://files.stlouisfed.org/files/htdocs/publications/review/13/01/Fawley.pdf)